# Scala and SparkJava, how to use lambda expressions

Tags: java, scala, lambda, frameworks, anonymous-class

I was using the [Spark](http://sparkjava.com/) framework in Java.
Now I want to use Scala.

I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to define a simple route in Scala.

In java I'd do it like this:

```
get('/article/:date', (req, res) -> {
  return "";
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Scala 2.12.x, Scala functions will attempt to be SAM converted directly into Java functions, so this works:

```
object Example {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    get("/article/:date", (req, res) => "")
  }
}
```

Otherwise, you'll need to explicitly implement the `handle` method on `Route`:

```
import spark.Spark.get
import spark.{Request, Response, Route}

object Example {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    get("/article/:date", new Route {
      override def handle(request: Request, response: Response) = ""
    })
  }
}
```

Or possibly provide some implicits to make functions compatible to `Route`:

```
object Example {
  implicit def func2ToRoute[T <: AnyRef](f: (Request, Response) => T): Route = new Route {
    override def handle(request: Request, response: Response) = f(request, response)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    get("/article/:date", (req: Request, res: Response) => "")
  }
}
```

Comment: I am trying the first option. Everything compiles nice and work nice except that my Scala IDE (The one based on eclipse from scala website) shows me an error: "missing parameter type" at (req, res)

Comment: I decided to add the parameter types, it still compiles and works but I get a different error in eclipse: `(x$1: String,x$2: spark.Route)Unit cannot be applied to (String, (spark.Request, spark.Response) ⇒ String)`

Comment: @ProNOOB I'm not really familiar with Eclipse. This compiles fine with IntelliJ.

Comment: Wow, Intellij makes my job much MUCH easier.